# Cygnus does not persist data into PostSQL

Tags: postgresql, fiware, fiware-cygnus

I am using the following tutorial to persist data in a PostGresQL database via Cygnus.

https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/513743/RWEcR2DC

When using a MySQL database with Cygnus everything works fine as you can see below:

```
mysql> SHOW tables FROM openiot;
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| Tables_in_openiot                                     |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| urn_ngsi-ld_TemperatureSensor_11401_TemperatureSensor |
| urn_ngsi-ld_TemperatureSensor_12435_TemperatureSensor |
| urn_ngsi-ld_TemperatureSensor_13477_TemperatureSensor |
| urn_ngsi-ld_TemperatureSensor_13828_TemperatureSensor |
| urn_ngsi-ld_TemperatureSensor_15205_TemperatureSensor |
| urn_ngsi-ld_TemperatureSensor_1546_TemperatureSensor  |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
109 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

But when using PostGres as backend, the NGSIPostgreSQLSink does not create tables.

Here is my setup on docker:

```
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    hostname: postgres
    expose:
      - "5432"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password"
      - "POSTGRES_USER=postgres"
      - "POSTGRES_DB=postgres"
    volumes:
      - data-postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    
  cygnus:
    image: fiware/cygnus-ngsi:latest
    hostname: cygnus
    depends_on:
        - postgres
    expose:
        - "5080"
    ports:
        - "5055:5055"
        - "5080:5080"
    environment:
        - "CYGNUS_POSTGRESQL_HOST=postgres"
        - "CYGNUS_POSTGRESQL_PORT=5432"
        - "CYGNUS_POSTGRESQL_USER=postgres"
        - "CYGNUS_POSTGRESQL_PASS=password"
        - "CYGNUS_POSTGRESQL_ENABLE_CACHE=true"
        - "CYGNUS_POSTGRESQL_SERVICE_PORT=5055"
        - "CYGNUS_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG"
        - "CYGNUS_API_PORT=5080"
        - "CYGNUS_SERVICE_PORT=5055"
```

If I list the schemas with a PostGres client there is no openiot schema:

```
postgres=# \dn
  List of schemas
  Name  |  Owner
--------+----------
 public | postgres
(1 row)
```

I also tried to mount the following agent.conf and cygnus_instance.conf files in docker:

docker

```
volumes:
   - ./conf/cygnus:/opt/apache-flume/conf/agent:ro
```

agent.conf

```
cygnus-ngsi.sources = http-source
cygnus-ngsi.sinks = postgresql-sink
cygnus-ngsi.channels = postgresql-channel


cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.channels = postgresql-channel
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.type = org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.port = 5050
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.NGSIRestHandler
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler.notification_target = /notify
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler.default_service = default
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler.default_service_path = /
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors = ts gi
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors.ts.type = timestamp
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.NGSIGroupingInterceptor$Builder
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.grouping_rules_conf_file = /usr/cygnus/conf/grouping_rules.conf
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors.nmi.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.NGSINameMappingsInterceptor$Builder
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors.nmi.name_mappings_conf_file = /usr/cygnus/conf/name_mappings.conf


cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.channel = postgresql-channel
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSIPostgreSQLSink
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.enable_encoding = false
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.enable_name_mappings = false
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.enable_grouping = false
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.enable_lowercase = false
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.postgresql_host = postgres
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.postgresql_port = 5432
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.postgresql_database = postgres
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.postgresql_username = postgres
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.postgresql_password = password
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.attr_persistence = column
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.data_model = by-service-path
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.batch_size = 100
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.batch_timeout = 30
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.batch_ttl = 10
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.persist_errors = true


cygnus-ngsi.channels.postgresql-channel.type = memory
cygnus-ngsi.channels.postgresql-channel.capacity = 100000
cygnus-ngsi.channels.postgresql-channel.transactionCapacity = 10000
```

cygnus_instance.conf

```
CYGNUS_USER=cygnus
CONFIG_FOLDER=/usr/cygnus/conf
CONFIG_FILE=/usr/cygnus/conf/agent.conf
AGENT_NAME=cygnusagent
LOGFILE_NAME=cygnus.log
ADMIN_PORT=8081
POLLING_INTERVAL=30
```

But to no avail Cygnus is still not persisting data in PostGres.

Here are some logs from the Cygnus service:

```
time=2022-03-10T17:02:12.429Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=defineOperation | msg=org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.ObjectMBean[809] : defineOperation start false:ACTION:Starts the instance

time=2022-03-10T17:02:12.429Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=defineOperation | msg=org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.ObjectMBean[863] : Method Cache: start()

time=2022-03-10T17:02:12.429Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=getMBeanInfo | msg=org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.ObjectMBean[318] : Method Annotation found for: stop

time=2022-03-10T17:02:12.429Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=defineOperation | msg=org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.ObjectMBean[809] : defineOperation stop false:ACTION:Stops the instance

time=2022-03-10T17:02:12.430Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=defineOperation | msg=org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.ObjectMBean[863] : Method Cache: stop()

time=2022-03-10T17:02:12.431Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=getMBeanInfo | msg=org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.ObjectMBean[286] : Influenced by: org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.Container

time=2022-03-10T17:02:12.431Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=getMBeanInfo | msg=org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.ObjectMBean[291] : Annotations not found for: org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.Container

time=2022-03-10T17:02:12.431Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=getMBeanInfo | msg=org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.ObjectMBean[286] : Influenced by: org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.Destroyable

time=2022-03-10T17:02:12.432Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=getMBeanInfo | msg=org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.ObjectMBean[318] : Method Annotation found for: destroy

time=2022-03-10T17:02:12.432Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=defineOperation | msg=org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.ObjectMBean[809] : defineOperation destroy false:ACTION:Destroys this component

time=2022-03-10T17:02:12.432Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=defineOperation | msg=org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.ObjectMBean[863] : Method Cache: destroy()

time=2022-03-10T17:02:12.432Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=getMBeanInfo | msg=org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.ObjectMBean[286] : Influenced by: org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.Dumpable

time=2022-03-10T17:02:12.433Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=getMBeanInfo | msg=org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.ObjectMBean[318] : Method Annotation found for: dump

time=2022-03-10T17:02:12.433Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=defineOperation | msg=org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.ObjectMBean[809] : defineOperation dump false:INFO:Dump the nested Object state as a String

time=2022-03-10T17:02:12.433Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=defineOperation | msg=org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.ObjectMBean[863] : Method Cache: dump()

time=2022-03-10T17:02:12.433Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=getMBeanInfo | msg=org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.ObjectMBean[286] : Influenced by: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler

time=2022-03-10T17:02:12.433Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=getMBeanInfo | msg=org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.ObjectMBean[305] : Attribute Annotation found for: getServer

time=2022-03-10T17:02:12.433Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=defineAttribute | msg=org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.ObjectMBean[657] : defineAttribute server false:true:class org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ErrorHandler:the jetty server for this handler

time=2022-03-10T17:02:12.433Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=defineAttribute | msg=org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.ObjectMBean[729] : passed convert checks server for type class org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server

time=2022-03-10T17:02:12.434Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=getMBeanInfo | msg=org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.ObjectMBean[318] : Method Annotation found for: destroy

time=2022-03-10T17:02:12.434Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=defineOperation | msg=org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.ObjectMBean[809] : defineOperation destroy false:ACTION:destroy associated resources

time=2022-03-10T17:02:12.434Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=defineOperation | msg=org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.ObjectMBean[863] : Method Cache: destroy()

time=2022-03-10T17:02:12.434Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=beanAdded | msg=org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.MBeanContainer[208] : Registered org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler:type=errorhandler,id=0

time=2022-03-10T17:02:12.434Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=addBean | msg=org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle[322] : org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@52e18a5d added {org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ErrorHandler@4a257334,AUTO}

time=2022-03-10T17:02:12.436Z | lvl=INFO | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=doStart | msg=org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server[372] : jetty-9.4.6.v20170531

time=2022-03-10T17:02:12.471Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=doStart | msg=org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler[110] : starting org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@52e18a5d

time=2022-03-10T17:02:12.471Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=setStarting | msg=org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle[185] : starting qtp260686092{STOPPED,8<=0<=200,i=0,q=0}

time=2022-03-10T17:02:12.488Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=setStarted | msg=org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle[177] : STARTED @1893ms qtp260686092{STARTED,8<=8<=200,i=7,q=0}

time=2022-03-10T17:02:12.488Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=beanAdded | msg=org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.MBeanContainer[131] : beanAdded ServerConnector@cc1c486{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:5055}->org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@52e18a5d

time=2022-03-10T17:02:12.489Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=beanAdded | msg=org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.MBeanContainer[131] : beanAdded ServerConnector@cc1c486{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:5055}->qtp260686092{STARTED,8<=8<=200,i=8,q=0}

time=2022-03-10T17:02:12.489Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=beanAdded | msg=org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.MBeanContainer[131] : beanAdded ServerConnector@cc1c486{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:5055}->org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ScheduledExecutorScheduler@36176a5b

ing | msg=org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle[185] : starting o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@30833221{/,null,UNAVAILABLE}

time=2022-03-10T17:02:12.551Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=<clinit> | msg=org.eclipse.jetty.http.PreEncodedHttpField[64] : HttpField encoders loaded: [org.eclipse.jetty.http.Http1FieldPreEncoder@5b3a334b]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's all good now I found the issue.

My subscription for Orion uses port 5050 (which is the port exposed if the agent is MySQL) for PostGresSINK the port exposed by the agent is 5055 so I updated the subscription and it works fine now.

"url": "http://cygnus:5055/notify"

Always be careful with copy N paste I just learned it the hard way ^^